# Test length of string in file

Tags: bash, shell-script, text-processing

I am not sure if I am using my argument correctly. I would like to pass in a argument which is a text file containing a string. When I run this script, it always enters the if statement even when the the number of characters of the string is below 32.

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ {$1} > 32 ]; then
    echo "Error: Password length invalid"
else
    echo "okay"
fi
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get string length of the variable by using `${#variable}`.  And you should use `-gt` instead of `>` in the `[` `]` expression.

```
#!/bin/bash -

pass=$(cat < "$1") || exit
if [ "${#pass}" -gt 32 ]; then
    echo >&2 "Error: Password length invalid"
    exit 1
else
    echo "okay"
fi
```

That counts the number of characters (interpreted in the current locale's encoding), not bytes, in the file passed as first argument except for the trailing newline characters, so for a file containing one line of text, that gives you the number of characters in that line.

Comment: This works with file as the argument. Thank you very much. I can't up vote your answer as I do not have enough reputation. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the file size with the command `stat -c %s <file>`. I haven't benchmarked that but it makes more sense to me to read the metadata directly, instead of loading every byte of the file to memory just to check its length.

Comment: That gives you a number of bytes, not characters though. And it does include the line delimiter. That also assumes the GNU implementation of `stat`. For symlinks, it gives you the size of the symlink instead of the size of the data in the file pointed to by the symlink.